# Validation of first 6 digits in a SQL query in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a requirement where I need to validate the identity card number with the first 6 digits as DOB. I need to find out the users not maintaining correct format.
If the dob is 02/10/1983 - 83021023456  &&  if its 02/10/2083 ->83221023456 (DOB is in MM/DD/YYYY and if year of birth >2000 then the +20 is done to the dob month). The query I tried with is given below:-

```
 SELECT f_account_name,F_SSN ,F_DOB  from table  where  
   CASE WHEN SUBSTR(to_char(F_DOB, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),0,4)>2000
   THEN
      SUBSTR(f_ssn,0,6) <>
      SUBSTR(to_char(F_DOB, 'YY-MM-DD'),0,2)
      ||SUBSTR(to_char(F_DOB, 'YY-MM-DD'),4,2)
      ||SUBSTR(to_char(F_DOB, 'YY-MM-DD'),7,2) 
    ELSE 
       SUBSTR(f_ssn,0,6) <>
        SUBSTR(to_char(F_DOB, 'YY-MM-DD'),0,2)
      ||(SUBSTR(to_char(F_DOB, 'YY-MM-DD'),4,2)+20)
      ||SUBSTR(to_char(F_DOB, 'YY-MM-DD'),7,2) 
      END;
```

Its not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the comparison inside the `CASE` expression; since the left-hand side of the expression is identical then it is simple to move it out and then you can simplify the rest:

```sql
SELECT f_account_name,
       F_SSN,
       F_DOB
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR(f_ssn,0,6) !=
         CASE
         WHEN EXTRACT( YEAR FROM F_DOB ) > 2000
         THEN TO_CHAR( F_DOB, 'YYMMDD')
         ELSE TO_CHAR( F_DOB, 'YY' )
              || TO_CHAR( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM F_DOB )+20, 'FM00' )
              || TO_CHAR( F_DOB, 'DD') 
         END;
```

or, if the rule is to add 20 to the month for each century past 1900 (i.e. 20XX add 20 and 21XX add 40, etc.) then:

```sql
SELECT f_account_name,
       F_SSN,
       F_DOB
FROM   table_name
WHERE  SUBSTR(f_ssn,0,6) != 
         TO_CHAR( F_DOB, 'YY' )
         || TO_CHAR(
              EXTRACT( MONTH FROM F_DOB )
              + 20 * GREATEST( TRUNC( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM F_DOB ) / 100 ) - 19, 0 ),
              'FM00'
            )
         || TO_CHAR( F_DOB, 'DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some date arithmetics and worked with numbers rather than strings ...

```
WITH
-- your input
indata(f_account_name,f_ssn,f_dob) AS (
                   --string -- number    -- string
            SELECT 'Arthur',83021023456,'02/10/1983' FROM dual
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Tricia',83221023456,'02/10/2083' FROM dual
) 
SELECT 
  f_account_name
, f_ssn
, f_dob
FROM indata
WHERE CAST(TRUNC(f_ssn/100000) AS NUMBER(6)) 
    -- ^ integer division by 100000 to get the first 6 digits ...
    =   MOD(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(f_dob,'MM/DD/YYYY')),100) * 10000
    -- ^ modulo year of date of 100 gives 3rd and 4th digit of year
      + (
          EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(f_dob,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
         +CASE 
            WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(f_dob,'MM/DD/YYYY')) >= 2000 THEN 20
            ELSE 0 
          END 
        ) * 100
      + EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE(f_dob,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
 ;
```